# Size of CustomElement does not match its contents

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

So if you inspect the shadowRoot of the CustomElement you see that the SVG is 48x48, but the operation-button is 48x52. Where are the extra 4 pixels coming from? What do I need to do to my :host to get those 4 pixels to disappear (changing to display: flex works but I want to understand what's happening).

```js
class SVGElement extends HTMLElement
{
    constructor()
    {
        super();

        this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});

        const style = document.createElement('style');
        style.textContent = `
:host
{
    all: initial;
    display: inline-block;
    contain: content;
}
svg
{
    border: solid 1px red;
}
`;

        this.shadowRoot.append(style);
    }

    createSVGElement(tag, attributes= {}, content = null)
    {
        const element = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', tag);
        for(const [attribute, value] of Object.entries(attributes))
            element.setAttributeNS(null, attribute, value);
        if(content)
            element.innerHTML = content;
        return element;
    }
}

class OperationButton extends SVGElement
{
    constructor()
    {
        super();

        const dimension = 36;

        const svg = this.createSVGElement('svg', {
            viewBox: `0 0 ${dimension} ${dimension}`
        });

        svg.append(this.createSVGElement('path', {
            //d: 'M10 2H2V34H10M26 2H34V34H26M9 18H27',
            d: 'M9 18H27M18 9V27',
            fill: 'none',
            stroke: '#40a829',
            'stroke-width': 4,
            'stroke-linecap': 'round',
            'stroke-linejoin': 'round',
        }));

        this.shadowRoot.append(svg);
    }

    connectedCallback()
    {
        if(this.hasAttribute('minus'))
        {
            const path = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('path');
            path.setAttribute('stroke', '#D2122E');
            path.setAttribute('d', 'M9 18H27');
        }
    }
}

customElements.define('operation-button', OperationButton);
```

```css
operation-button
{
  width:3em;
  border: solid 1px blue;
}
```

```html
<operation-button></operation-button>
```

Comment: You Web Component can be optimized, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77133659/how-do-i-use-the-icon-from-the-svg-sprite-directly-in-the-css-scss/77141826#